# Slow product page because of product images

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, product-images

My productpages are quite slow when loading for the first time (15+ sec), because the product image cache is not available for that product. (checked it with the Profiler)

When the product image cache is available page loads within 1,5 sec.

How can I easily improve this? For example crawl pages or create automatically product image cache.

I am running Magento 1.9.3.2

Comment: Can you clarify what version of Magento you are using. My answer is compatible for Magento 2.x.

Comment: @AshSmith Thanks, but I am running Magento 1.9.3.2.

Answer (score 0):

You could hook up `bin/magento catalog:images:resize` to a cron task. That would generate all the cached images at the required sizes as you require.

For example:

```
$ crontab -e

# Cron entry to run every day at midnight:
0 0 * * * [pathtomagento]/bin/magento catalog:images:resize >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Thanks! Is something also possible for Magento 1?